# HMACSHA1 SSL issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, sha1, hmac

I have the following code which creates a hash from a password and then compares it with a stored hashed password in the db. All works fine over http. This for an asp.net webforms application running under c# 4.0

```
HMACSHA1 hash = new HMACSHA1();
hash.Key = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
encodedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password)));
```

However when running over https/ssl the encoded password is different and therefore the user cannot login.

Does the .net framework do something different when computing hash when going over SSL?

If I step through the code and copy the encoded password and update my db then over SSL I can login.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: The SSL is transparent to the asp.net, I do not understand where and how the passwords travel from client to server and where the compare is done.

Comment: Why do you use an HMAC and then pass as key and data-to-be-hashed the password? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: robert, not my code its part of opensource cms umbraco. just trying to fix an issue that i have discovered and it seems to be that over https the encoding is different when over http possibly something going on in the depths of the .net framework?

Comment: Suggest looking at the http headers like "accept-encoding" perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Please try setting Globalization settings as defined in MSDN article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/39d1w2xf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

This will ensure that the hash.key is uniform across your application which in turn, will ensure that the computed hash is identical every time it is computed with a key.